# C# The TreeView.Nodes.find method returns a collection of length > 0, but the index of returned node is 0

Tags: c#, treeview

I have a TreeView on my form that gets populated by user input. There are three values: Game night, division, and player name.

The Treeview is organized by these values. Meaning division is a child of game night, and player name a child of division.

When I add a player to the TreeView with a division that already exists, the search for that node returns a collection of one treenode, but the node has an index of 0 - causing an error when trying to add the player to that division.

Here's my code:

```
    private void AddPlayerToTreeView(string playerName, string division, DateTime selDate)
    {
        TreeNode tn = new TreeNode();
        string shrtDate = selDate.ToShortDateString();

        //check to see if the date exists (shortdate format)
        // if doesn't exist: create the Night node and call the function recursively
        // if exists, check to see if division exists:
        //   if doesn't exist: create the Division node and call the function recursively
        //   if exists, add player


        TreeNode[] tns = this.tview_roster.Nodes.Find(shrtDate, false); //find the date in the root nodes

        if(tns.Length == 0) //the date doesn't exist in the list
        {
            tn = this.tview_roster.Nodes.Add(shrtDate, shrtDate);
            tn.ImageIndex = 2; //date icon

            this.AddPlayerToTreeView(playerName, division, selDate);
        }
        else //date exists, try to find division within it
        {
            var parentNight = tns[0].Index; //save the index of the night node

            tns = this.tview_roster.Nodes.Find(division, true); //search child nodes

            if (tns.Length == 0) //division doesn't exist, create it (and child nodes in recursive call)
            {
                tn = this.tview_roster.Nodes[parentNight].Nodes.Add(division, division);
                tn.ImageIndex = 1; //division icon

                this.AddPlayerToTreeView(playerName, division, selDate);
            }
            else //division exists, add player
            {
                var parentDiv = tns[0].Index; //THIS INDEX IS ALWAYS 0

                tn = this.tview_roster.Nodes[parentNight].Nodes[parentDiv].Nodes.Add(playerName, playerName);
                tn.ImageIndex = 0; //player icon
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, the issue arises at this line:

> var parentDiv = tns[0].Index; //THIS INDEX IS ALWAYS 0

Any help would be appreciated, and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the issue and figured I'd answer my question in case this might help others.

The problem was I wasn't pointing to the parent node (parentNight) when searching for the child node (division).

Here's my updated and functional code:

```
    private void AddPlayerToTreeView(string playerName, string division, DateTime selDate)
    {
        TreeNode tn = new TreeNode();
        string shrtDate = selDate.ToShortDateString();

        //check to see if the date exists (shortdate format)
        // if doesn't exist: create the Night node and call the function recursively
        // if exists, check to see if division exists:
        //   if doesn't exist: create the Division node and call the function recursively
        //   if exists, add player


        TreeNode[] tns = this.tview_roster.Nodes.Find(shrtDate, false); //find the date in the root nodes

        if(tns.Length == 0) //the date doesn't exist in the list
        {
            tn = this.tview_roster.Nodes.Add(shrtDate, shrtDate);
            tn.ImageIndex = 2; //date icon

            this.AddPlayerToTreeView(playerName, division, selDate);
        }
        else //date exists, try to find division within it
        {
            var parentNight = tns[0].Index; //save the index of the night node

            tns = this.tview_roster.Nodes[parentNight].Nodes.Find(division, false); //search child nodes

            if (tns.Length == 0) //division doesn't exist, create it (and child nodes in recursive call)
            {
                tn = this.tview_roster.Nodes[parentNight].Nodes.Add(division, division);
                tn.ImageIndex = 1; //division icon

                this.AddPlayerToTreeView(playerName, division, selDate);
            }
            else //division exists, add player
            {
                var parentDiv = tns[0].Index; //save the index of the division node

                tn = this.tview_roster.Nodes[parentNight].Nodes[parentDiv].Nodes.Add(playerName, playerName);
                tn.ImageIndex = 0; //player icon
            }
        }
    }
```